# Access system version from pom.xml into JSP (Maven + Spring)

Tags: spring, jsp, maven, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to access the version of my system (defined into pom.xml) from a JSP. It's the login screen, so no action was called before.

Is there a way to Spring read the version number from my pom and put it into request / session?

Thanks a lot for the attention!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform [resource filtering](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html) with Maven. Given the following in `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <system.version>1.2.3.4</system.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

any file in `src/main/resources` with a placeholder `${some.property}`, where `some.property` resolves to a property in the `pom.xml`, will be replaced by the value of that property. For example, if you had a property file `globals.properties` like

```
system.version=${system.version}
```

Maven would filter the file and change it to

```
system.version=1.2.3.4
```

You can then have Spring inject that property with a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and `@Value`.